# Synchronizing step function lambda map iterator

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-step-functions

I have two lambdas (lambda1 and lambda2) that are orchestrated in a step function map iterator. Hence I have list of events, E = [e1, e2, ..., e10], that acts as input to this state machine map iterator. This works beautifully, lambda1 is invoked with e1 as input and passes on its output to lambda2. This all works as intended and through the parallel workflow all events are processed simultaneously.

However, I would like to add some kind of logic between lambda1 and lambda2 where I make sure that no lambda2 is invoked until all parallel events has successfully been processed. The events, E = [e1, e2, ..., e10], might differ several minutes in the time it takes to finish and lambda2 performs a none idempotent operation. Due to this fact, I want to avoid running any lambda2 until all events, E, are successfully handled by lambda1. But once they are successfully handled I want to lambda2 to process the output of lambda1.

Is this kind of lambda orchestration too complex to create without involving other resources like SNS/SQS or state handling in a dynamodb (just to mention a few approaches)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution. The tricky was to add a pass state in between the map iterators. I also had a problem with passing the output from the pass-state to lambda2 iterator. It was first passed as a list:

```
[
  {object_iteration1}
  {object_iteration2}
          .
          .
]
```

However, this didn't make for a valid input for the lambda2 iterator map. This got solved by adding the output under parameters such as:

```
"pass-state": {
  "Type": "Pass",
  "Parameters": {
    "lambda1_output.$": "$"
  },
  "Next": "Lambda2"
},
```

I'm still unclear why it works. But it does. Perhaps someone in the future can elaborate further. The step function now works as intended and I will leave it here for someone else.

[image]